# Admin-On-Rest Customizing Inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form, admin-on-rest

I have a User Resource, which referenced by many other resources.
So I want to create a UserResourceInput :

```
import React from 'react';
import {ReferenceInput, SelectInput} from 'admin-on-rest';


const UserReferenceInput = (props) => (
    <ReferenceInput reference="user" {...props}>
        <SelectInput optionText="name"/>
    </ReferenceInput>
);
UserReferenceInput.defaultProps = {
    source: 'userId',
    addLabel: true,
    label: 'User'
};

export default UserReferenceInput;
```

And Use it in simple form like this:

```
ProductCreate = (props) => (
    <Create {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
            <TextInput source="title" />
            <NumberInput source="price" />
            <UserReferenceInput />
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
);
```

But I get this Error:
[image]

Comment: How do you get `props` from the input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `source` prop on the `ReferenceInput`. Hence, it can't find value for it. You can define it either inside the `UserReferenceInput` directly or pass it as prop to the `UserReferenceInput` in your form.

**Edit**

Don't use the `addLabel` prop on the `ReferenceInput`, it does not support it. Instead, apply it on the `SelectInput` child.

Comment: The source is in defaultProps.

Comment: thanks but `addField:true` also is needed for it to work.